# Como selecionar todas as imagens existentes e adicionar um atributo a elas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Então estou tentando selecionar todas as imagens existentes e cheguei a desenvolver esse código

```
(function ($) {

    var elementsImg = document.getElementsByTagName('img'), len, i;

    for (i=0, len=elementsImg.length; i<len; i++) {  
       elementsImg[i].setAttribute('loading','lazy');     
    }  

})(jQuery);
```

Contudo, no console do devtools ele aparece como
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber uma possível de solução e o que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: Não está fazendo nada de errado. O método `setAttribute` não tem retorno algum, por isso aparece `undefined`.

Comment: inspecionando as imagens, elas ficaram com os atributos modificados?

Comment: @AndréWalker Sim, os atributos foram modificados mas pensei que usando o console.log do jeito que eu fiz acima ele iria retornar os elementos img que foram adicionado o atributo  "loading". Contudo agora eu entendi pela explicação acima e abaixo o porque de está retornando "undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código aparentemente está correto. Você não recebe um valor de retorno no console do seu navegador por conta do comportamento do método [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute), que não retorna valor algum. Quando nenhum valor é retornado de uma expressão, exibirá `undefined` no console; inclusive a própria chamada da função `console.log` exibirá o valor que foi passado como argumento e `undefined` logo em seguida, dado que `console.log` não retorna valor algum:

```
console.log(1)

1
undefined
```

Para verificar se os atributos foram inseridos nas imagens você pode utilizar o método [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) como no exemplo:

```
elementsImg[i].getAttribute('loading');
```

Retornando o valor do atributo. Caso o método não encontre o atributo retornará `null`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! agora eu entendi o motivo do retorno "undefined".